# Query for mysql to compare 2 fields

Tags: mysql

I merged two tables into one. And Now need to sort out the NI number column that exists on the both tables before merging.

So Column1 has some valid values into it and Column2 which was copied from the other table has some valid values.

Now need to compare them a copy the valid ones into a new column

```
Column1   |  Column2
xxx       |  SH178076A
SH178076A |  zzzz
SH178076A |  zzzz
xxx       |  SH178076A
xxx       |  SH178076A
```

Like this. So the checking needs which field has 9 characters into it then copy it over to a new column from them by comparing.

Comment: So.. what you tried? Show us the code.

Comment: which part of this are you stuck on then? Did you try to break the problem down into parts and tackle each part separately?

Comment: Are you sure that the data in the column that you dont want is NEVER also 9 characters?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].